# Can I set a geometry using QGIS editing tools for a feature without geometry?

Tags: qgis, editing

I have a PostGIS point layer with mixed features (with and without geometry). When a non geometry feature is selected from attribute table I don´t know how to set its geometry with QGIS editing tools. The add spatial object is only for new features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add geometry to attribute only feature with **Add Part** function from *Advanced digitizing toolbar*

[image]